# Twitter v2 APIs: Accessing monthly tweet cap via API

Tags: twitter

My app invokes the Twitter v2 APIs to retrieve users tweets.

According to the [Twitter Dev Portal](https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/dashboard) I have a monthly tweet cap of 500,000 tweets that I can retrieve, and this UI tells me how much I've used.

However, is there any way to retrieve this data via an API?

[This page](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview#tweet-cap) seems to imply it's just via the UI, but I'm surprised there is no way to retrieve this via an API. Is there any such way even for v1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v1.1 had no volume cap, but does have rate limits, which you can access via the HTTP headers on GET requests. POST requests are different, and managed at the user account level.

In v2, at the time of writing, there is currently no way to access the cap and volume data via the API - it is only available in the UI.

Comment: OK, thanks for the reply. Is it likely this will be added at some point?

Comment: Also, is a 429 returned when this occurs and does it contain the x-rate-limit-reset header that tells us when we can resume?

Comment: I believe there's an error message (not certain on the error code) when the cap is hit; you cannot rely on the `x-rate-limit-*` headers related to the monthly cap as they relate to call frequency, not to data volume. There are several open requests on the API feedback site relating to this and the product team may add something in future, but there is no specific timeframe.